# Why is "Download CSV" repeated in my charts dropdown?

Tags: highcharts

[image: Repeated Choices]

I can't figure out why Download CSV and Download XLS are repeated in my Highstock chart. Here are my links:

```
<script src="/Scripts/HighStock/highstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="/Scripts/HighStock/highcharts-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/HighStock/modules/no-data-to-display.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/HighStock/modules/boost.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/HighStock/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/HighStock/modules/export-csv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. I had a duplicate link to csport-csv.js in my html. It was hiding somewhere I didn't think to look. Once it was removed the chart displayed the expected choices.